# Can a Core Data entity have relation with itself?

Tags: ios, core-data

Can a Core Data entity have a relation with itself ?
Something like a Self Join  ?

Comment: Yes, that is the only way things like Employee and Manager and stuff is possible to be modeled in Coredata

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No problems. Just create an entity like Person, then you can create a Manager which is a Person, and Coworkers as Many People. I know this example is contrived, but this is straight forward.

Remember that unlike strings which are stored in the object, the Person in manager and coworkers are just pointers.

Comment: So, in the graphical interface of Core data Model, I can link a relationship back to the object ?

Comment: You can only do non-native through relationships. So You make a relationship called "spouse", and you put Destination as Person and Inverse as Spouse. Then you go in the Editor menu and pick Create NSManagedObject subclass. Just keep in mind if this is one to one or to many. Then in code you can do, Person *p1; Person *p2; Instantiate them and after that you can do p1.spouse = p2; and the opposite connection is done for you, so you don't have to do p2.spouse = p1; The way I got this to stick in my brain was to think that relationships is for pointers to my own objects

Comment: Just remember, you never do Alloc and Init on NSManagedObjects, you do this to instantiate : Person *p1 = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]; It seems like a mouthful, but it really isn't

Comment: That I know, i have used it once but had never encountered a self join kind of situation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is what the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html) says:

> A relationship specifies the entity, or the parent entity, of the
>   objects at the destination. This can be the same as the entity at the
>   source (a reflexive relationship).